# Why can't we define any $C^{\infty}$ structure on the single point $0 \in \Bbb R^n$?

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

I'm studying the book "Differentiable Manifolds" by Brickell &Clark .  On page 94,   in  the example 6.3.6, it was written that we can't define any $C^{\infty}$ structure on the single point $0$. Isn't the single point $0$ a $C^{\infty}$ manifold of dimension 0?

Thank you for your any help.

Comment: How do you differentiate a function defined just at one point?

Comment: It's a matter of convention. One possible convention, as your book and @TedShifrin mentioned, is to say that a singleton is not a $C^\infty$ manifold because it doesn't make sense to differentiate a function defined only at one point. But another convention (which I use in my books, and is more useful, in my opinion) is to declare every function from $\mathbb R^0$ to $\mathbb R^k$ to be smooth, because it can be (vacuously) differentiated arbitrarily many times with respect to each coordinate function (all none of them). With this definition, every $0$-manifold has a unique smooth structure.

Comment: Well, yeah, I guess we want Stokes to apply to compact 1-manifolds with boundary. I guess I tend not to worry about such bits of pedantry.

Comment: @TedShifrin: Not only. You also want transversality to work so that point- preimages to be submanifolds as well. And so on. A more interesting point is that you want the empty set to be a smooth $n$-manifold for every $n\ge 0$!

Comment: Yes, @MoisheKohan, of course.

Comment: @Jack Lee: Thank you so much for your comment.